# Lose selection of a JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, treetablecelleditor

When you click on a JTable cell, the row becomes "selected", I want it so that when I click on anything else, it becomes unselected.

I'm thinking of doing this with a mouse listener on the table but not sure how to recognize (click not on table). Any ideas?

This is what I'm trying:

```
 jTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                    System.out.println("click");}});
```

But it only prints click when I click in the first column and surely not when I click on something that's not the table.

When I recognize that event I'd call this method:

```
public void loseCellFocus()
{
    jTable.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
    jTable.clearSelection();
}
```

Comment: Use a `FocusListener` attached to the `JTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `FocusListener` attached to the `JTable`, this will tell you when focus moves away from the table.

See [How to Write a Focus Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) for more details

For example...

```
    table.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            loseCellFocus();
        }           
    });
```

This will, of course, only work when keyboard focus is transferred to a new component capable for receiving keyboard focus

> This causes my loseCellFocus() method to be called right away, as soon as I click on any cell it's called

You could use [`JTable#setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(boolean)) or check to see if the component that focus has been transferred to is a child of the `JTable`

For example...

```
table.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        if (e.getOppositeComponent().getParent() != table) {
            loseCellFocus();
        }
    }
});
```

## Runnable Example...

Okay, that got messy.  Not only did I have to add a `FocusListener` to the `JTable`, but I had to make sure one was added to the `TableCellEditor` component :P

This is a proof of concept only, I'd have specialised classes which capable for either raising events or triggering the required functionality via some common interface

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(10, 10));

            JTextField editorField = new JTextField(10);
            editorField.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
            editorField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                    TableCellEditor cellEditor = table.getCellEditor();
                    if (cellEditor != null) {
                        if (!cellEditor.stopCellEditing()) {
                            cellEditor.cancelCellEditing();
                        }
                    }

                    Component gotFocus = e.getOppositeComponent();
                    if (!gotFocus.equals(table)) {
                        table.clearSelection();
                    }
                }
            });
            DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(editorField);
            table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, editor);

            add(new JScrollPane(table));
            table.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                    Component gotFocus = e.getOppositeComponent();
                    if (!gotFocus.getParent().equals(table)) {
                        TableCellEditor cellEditor = table.getCellEditor();
                        if (cellEditor != null) {
                            if (!cellEditor.stopCellEditing()) {
                                cellEditor.cancelCellEditing();
                            }
                        }
                        table.clearSelection();
                    }
                }

            });

            JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
            add(field, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

    }

}
```

## AWTEventListener Example...

Okay, didn't really want to go this route as it ends up in a mess of cross conditions, but.  Basically this monitors ALL `MouseEvent` and `FocusEvent`s, it does some backwards summersults to test for valid conditions (as we need to make sure that not only if a `JTable` is part of the event, but if the editor is part of the event) and based on those results, stops cell editing and clears the selection...

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(5, 5));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(new JScrollPane(table), gbc);
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);

            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                    if (event instanceof FocusEvent) {
                        FocusEvent focusEvent = (FocusEvent) event;
                        if (focusEvent.getID() == FocusEvent.FOCUS_LOST) {
                            Component focusTo = focusEvent.getOppositeComponent();
                            Component focusFrom = focusEvent.getComponent();

                            JTable table = getTableFrom(focusFrom);
                            if (focusTo == null || !focusTo.getParent().equals(table)) {

                                stopCellEditing(table);
                                clearSelection(table);

                            }
                        }
                    } else if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
                        MouseEvent mouseEvent = (MouseEvent) event;
                        if (mouseEvent.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED) {
                            Component focusOwner = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();
                            JTable table = getTableFrom(focusOwner);
                            System.out.println("     table = " + table);
                            System.out.println("focusOwner = " + focusOwner);
//                          if ((table != null && mouseEvent.getComponent() != table) || (focusOwner != null && !focusOwner.getParent().equals(table))) {
                            if ((table != null && mouseEvent.getComponent() != table) && (focusOwner != null && !focusOwner.getParent().equals(table))) {
                                stopCellEditing(table);
                                clearSelection(table);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                protected JTable getTableFrom(Component component) {
                    JTable table = null;
                    if (component instanceof JTable) {
                        table = (JTable) component;
                    } else if (component != null && component.getParent() instanceof JTable) {
                        table = (JTable) component.getParent();
                    }
                    return table;
                }

                protected void clearSelection(JTable table) {
                    if (table != null) {
                        table.clearSelection();
                    }
                }

                protected void stopCellEditing(JTable table) {

                    if (table != null) {
                        TableCellEditor cellEditor = table.getCellEditor();
                        if (cellEditor != null) {
                            if (!cellEditor.stopCellEditing()) {
                                cellEditor.cancelCellEditing();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, AWTEvent.FOCUS_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
        }

    }

}
```

This example basically works for ALL `JTable`s (once the `AWTEventListener` is registered), but you could configure it to monitor a single table, by changing some of the event sources and comparing them to each other :P

Comment: Sounds perfect! Trying now

Comment: This causes my `loseCellFocus()` method to be called right away, as soon as I click on any cell it's called

Comment: You could use [`JTable#setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(boolean)) or check to see if the component that focus has been transferred to is a child of the `JTable`

Comment: Thankyou for your help, unfortunately neither of those two suggestions worked. I'm guessing it's because of my table renderer or editor, so i'll try looking through those and see if I can get it to work with what you've told me. Thanks.

Comment: I've added a working example, it got a little complicated :P

Comment: I've managed to get it working somewhat after reading your example, thanks! However it only works if the click that makes it lose focus can have a focus. So if I select a cell, and then click a (differen't table's) cell then the original cell will no longer be selected, which is good, same if I click the buttons on the page, or even the minimize button. However if I click on just the background then nothing happens.

Comment: @Aequitas Yeah, that's a difficult one.  You could use `Toolkit.addAWTEventListener` to monitor both the `focus` and `mouse` events, but it quickly becomes messy.  Let me see if I can come up with a working example

Comment: I've tried adding a "mouseclicked" mouse listener to the panel to `requestFocus` but that does nothing

Comment: So instead of the panel.requestFocus I can make an arbitrary button gain focus on the panel click, kind of a hack but it's okay I guess, is there a way I can make the button lose focus immediately after gaining focus? `button.unrequestFocus`

Comment: Sorry for asking so many questions but, also it only works if I click on that particular panel, is there a way for if I click on any where in the frame, all children panels of it?

Comment: The problem is trying to come up with a solution which will cover ALL possible scenarios, when you can't possible predict in what kind of hierarchy the table might be placed in. I've done a `AWTEventListener` example, it gets a little convoluted as it needs to do multiple checks against one source of the event or another to determine what it should, if anything at all

Answer (score 1):

I did this sometime back with a `JTree`. The focus listener etc. did not work. Finally the solution I used is to use `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener` and capture keyboard and mouse events. Look for the `JTree` in the component hierarchy of the event and call a method to remove the selection if the item doesn't belong to the tree.

I can search for the code if you need.

**Edit**

The AWTEventListener in the accepted answer is a bit more complicated than needed.

```
        final AWTEventListener focusTracker = new AWTEventListener() {
            @Override public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                if (event.getID() != MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED && event.getID() != KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)
                    return;
                if (!isPartOfTable((Component) event.getSource())) {
                    if (table.isEditing()) {
                        TableCellEditor cellEditor = table.getCellEditor();
                        cellEditor.cancelCellEditing();
                    }
                    table.clearSelection();
                    table.dispatchEvent(new FocusEvent(table, FocusEvent.FOCUS_LOST));
                }
            }

            protected boolean isPartOfTable(Component component) {
                while (component != null && component != table)
                    component = component.getParent();
                return component == table;
            }

        };
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(focusTracker, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
```

Note: You need to remove the listener when the frame is closed. I did not like the table cell still being highlighted when clicked outside. So I am posting a focus lost event to the table.